# how to Join two column in datarow array in Select statement?

Tags: c#, datarow

I have two column `Name` and `Family` in my database (table name : Member).
I want to search list of Member using name + family (full name), but  I don't have full name in column.
I use this code for search in `Name` Column :

```
SearchResult = new Member().List().Select(string.Format("Name = '{0}'",txt_Checkout_Member.Text));
```

but how can I perform search on Fullname (name column + family column) ?

Comment: What does List() return?

Comment: This code doesn't search anything. Where is the code that actually does the search? Which database are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, other)? Which data access technology are you using? ADO.NET, NHibernate, Entity Framework?

Comment: DataTable, It is the procedure that is for all tables in database, and return all data (select * from).

Comment: `List` Return all data, and this code search on all data that come from SQL SERVER database, and I'm using ADO.net

Comment: This is **very** inefficient. You should execute different SQL queries to return only the data you need. Anyway, you *can* specify multiple criteria in a select statement, in a manner similar to SQL's `SELECT`

Comment: So you don't want to save non-useful data but you SELECT and transfer all columns of all rows to filter them in c#?

Comment: As Panagiotis says this doesn't search anything, and says that this returns all the data is not enough information since you aren't saying what the data is like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple criteria in a Select method,eg:

```
myTable.Select(string.Format("Name = '{0}' AND Family='{1}",name,surname));
```

This is a very inefficient way to load data though, as you load an entire table when you probably only need a single line. That's why such a technique is never used in production code unless the table contains very few rows that you want to cache.

The typical way is to write a SQL statement that returns only the rows you need. You can write your own parameterized queries, or you can do use Visual Studio's dataset designer, by right-clicking on an adapter and selecting "Add Query". Write the SQL statement and define any parameters as you would in SQL (eg @name, @family). The designer will create a method that executes the query and returns a datatable with the results

Comment: thanks for your help, but which one do you think is better  when I want to search using different column (such as name,family,Id,etc)? 1.load all data and search using `Select`. 2.Create many procedure for search using different column (such as GetData_FromId,GetData_FromName,GetData_FromAge, etc) I mean create one procedure for each search column because It isn't possible to create one for all.?

Answer (score 0):

You can select and CONCATWS 2 column:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', name, family) AS full_name
```

in your SQL query.

Comment: I want to perform this in c# program not in SQL, because I don't want to save or send not useful data

Comment: But that's what you *are* doing now - loading everything when you only need a single line

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to doing this in C# however to filter via concatenation in Linq is like this:

```
SearchResult = new Member().List().Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.Name, x.Family) == txt_Checkout_Member.Text));
```

This works if the datatable is a one made by a dataset. If it isn't replace x.Name and x.Family with x.ItemArray[column number]